# Run a canvas application locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing an MVC 3 Canvas app. Is it possible to debug locally rather than hosting it somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am developing some app in PHP at the moment, but I guess the language doesn't matter. Just set the app address to your local development address. The page is loaded in an iframe, so your computer maps it to whatever it thinks is the correct ip. Facebook doesn't care about where the page is hosted.

However, the communication of the API with facebook will be a bit slower than between Facebook and your production server. So don't worry if the App seems to be very slow.